# Double-byte white space

Tags: sql, database

How do we find double-byte white spaces in an SQL table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "double white space" you mean two spaces, then you can use `like`:

```
 where col like '%  %'
```

If you mean something more general, then you need to specify the database.  You'll probably need regular expressions and that functionality differs by database.

Comment: Sir by your answer do you mean the wildcards, like this: SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '%es%';
The query will select the city containing es pattern,

Comment: @ZiaUllah . . . Yes, that is what this is suggesting.